# Differences between SP initiated SSO and IDP initiated SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, openam

Can anyone explain to me what the main differences between **SP initiated SSO** and **IDP initiated SSO** are, including which would be the better solution for implementing single sign on in conjunction with ADFS + OpenAM Federation?

Comment: To clarify for anyone new to single sign on concepts: SP = service provider (the system the user wants to utilize) and IdP = identify provider (the system that authenticates the user)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**IDP Initiated SSO**

From PingFederate documentation :- https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pf_sm_supportedStandards_pf82/page/task/idpInitiatedSsoPOST.html

In this scenario, a user is logged on to the IdP and attempts to access a resource on a remote SP server. The SAML assertion is transported to the SP via HTTP POST.

Processing Steps:

1. A user has logged on to the IdP.
2. The user requests access to a protected SP resource. The user is not logged on to the SP site.
3. Optionally, the IdP retrieves attributes from the user data store.
4. The IdP’s SSO service returns an HTML form to the browser with a SAML response containing the authentication assertion and any additional attributes. The browser automatically posts the HTML form back to the SP.

**SP Initiated SSO**

From PingFederate documentation:- http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/SP-Initiated+SSO--POST-POST

In this scenario a user attempts to access a protected resource directly on an SP Web site without being logged on. The user does not have an account on the SP site, but does have a federated account managed by a third-party IdP. The SP sends an authentication request to the IdP. Both the request and the returned SAML assertion are sent through the user’s browser via HTTP POST.

Processing Steps:

1. The user requests access to a protected SP resource. The request is redirected to the federation server to handle authentication.
2. The federation server sends an HTML form back to the browser with a SAML request for authentication from the IdP. The HTML form is automatically posted to the IdP’s SSO service.
3. If the user is not already logged on to the IdP site or if re-authentication is required, the IdP asks for credentials (e.g., ID and password) and the user logs on.
4. Additional information about the user may be retrieved from the user data store for inclusion in the SAML response. (These attributes are predetermined as part of the federation agreement between the IdP and the SP)
5. The IdP’s SSO service returns an HTML form to the browser with a SAML response containing the authentication assertion and any additional attributes. The browser automatically posts the HTML form back to the SP. **NOTE:** SAML specifications require that POST responses be digitally signed.
6. (Not shown) If the signature and assertion are valid, the SP establishes a session for the user and redirects the browser to the target resource.

Comment: Re SP Initiated SSO - point 3 above says "If the user is not already logged on to the IdP site or if re-authentication is required, the IdP asks for credentials (e.g., ID and password) and the user logs on."  How does the system determine if the user is logged on to the IdP site?  Does it generate a cookie, for example?

Comment: @Edwardo Your assumption is correct. When a session is established with an IdP, typically the IdP generates a cookie to maintain that session.

Comment: I have another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861315/how-to-maintain-state-parameter-in-identity-provider-idp-initiated-saml-sso . Can you have a look at it ?

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: [IdP-initiated SSO—POST](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-93/page/bgz1564002957929.html),  
[SP-initiated SSO—POST-POST](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-93/page/ani1564002957424.html)

Answer (score 79):

## SP Initiated SSO

Bill the user: "Hey Jimmy, show me that report"

Jimmy the SP: "Hey, I'm not sure who you are yet. We have a process here so you go get yourself verified with Bob the IdP first. I trust him."

Bob the IdP: "I see Jimmy sent you here. Please give me your credentials."

Bill the user: "Hi I'm Bill. Here are my credentials."

Bob the IdP: "Hi Bill. Looks like you check out."

Bob the IdP: "Hey Jimmy. This guy Bill checks out and here's some additional information about him. You do whatever you want from here."

Jimmy the SP: "Ok cool. Looks like Bill is also in our list of known  guests. I'll let Bill in."

## IdP Initiated SSO

Bill the user: "Hey Bob. I want to go to Jimmy's place. Security is tight over there."

Bob the IdP: "Hey Jimmy. I trust Bill. He checks out and here's some additional information about him. You do whatever you want from here."

Jimmy the SP: "Ok cool. Looks like Bill is also in our list of known  guests. I'll let Bill in."

---

I go into more detail here, but still keeping things simple: https://jorgecolonconsulting.com/saml-sso-in-simple-terms/.

Comment: I don't think the second conversation is right....instead it should be: IdP: "Hey, here's some info about Sal, please let her in" / SP: "Ok, I trust you, I'll let her in"

Comment: the first conversation is also not right:  in the first step SP does not know anything about which user it is yet, only at IdP the user will log in and identify itself as "Sal"

Comment: The first conversation should be: SP:"Hey, where is your ID?" IdP: "Hold on, I'll check it. Let me see your ID please. Ok bro let her in, she's named Sal and she's 21 (optionally)" SP: "Cool dude, your awesome! Hey you, come on in!"

Comment: I believe that this answer does not deserv the down votes that it got. It answers the question in a creative way, maybe not as accurate as some have pointed out, but creative non the less.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the correct answer in this format. My eyes are glazing over reading the up-voted answers, this format helps grab the general concept very quickly.

I don't know enough to confidently create an answer based on the comments myself.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a more accurate conversation a couple of months ago

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem right that the IdP is directly talking to the SP. The correct alternative for it will be that IdP gives a securely signed message to the user who brings it back to the SP, because the redirection and the POST data is going through user's browser, not from server to server.

Answer (score 75):

In IDP Init SSO (Unsolicited Web SSO) the Federation process is initiated by the IDP sending an unsolicited SAML Response to the SP. In SP-Init, the SP generates an AuthnRequest that is sent to the IDP as the first step in the Federation process and the IDP then responds with a SAML Response. IMHO ADFSv2 support for SAML2.0 Web SSO SP-Init is  stronger than its IDP-Init support re: integration with 3rd Party Fed products (mostly revolving around support for RelayState) so if you have a choice you'll want to use SP-Init as it'll probably make life easier with ADFSv2.

Here are some simple SSO descriptions from the PingFederate 8.0 Getting Started Guide that you can poke through that may help as well -- https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf80/index.shtml#gettingStartedGuide/task/idpInitiatedSsoPOST.html

Answer (score 0):

https://support.procore.com/faq/what-is-the-difference-between-sp-and-idp-initiated-sso

There is much more to this but this is a high level overview on which is which.

Procore supports both SP- and IdP-initiated SSO:

Identity Provider Initiated (IdP-initiated) SSO. With this option, your end users must log into your Identity Provider's SSO page (e.g., Okta, OneLogin, or Microsoft Azure AD) and then click an icon to log into and open the Procore web application. To configure this solution, see Configure IdP-Initiated SSO for Microsoft Azure AD, Configure Procore for IdP-Initated Okta SSO, or Configure IdP-Initiated SSO for OneLogin.
OR
Service Provider Initiated (SP-initiated) SSO. Referred to as Procore-initiated SSO, this option gives your end users the ability to sign into the Procore Login page and then sends an authorization request to the Identify Provider (e.g., Okta, OneLogin, or Microsoft Azure AD). Once the IdP authenticates the user's identify, the user is logged into Procore. To configure this solution, see Configure Procore-Initiated SSO for Microsoft Azure Active Directory, Configure Procore-Initiated SSO for Okta, or Configure Procore-Initiated SSO for OneLogin.