# SAML reponse difference between SP initiated SSO and IDP initiated SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

How to tell from a SAML response if it's a SP initiated SSO or an IDP initiated SSO? Is there an attribute which tells me who initiated the SSO?

For example in this StackOverflow Question: [Differences between SP initiated SSO and IDP initiated SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779532/differences-between-sp-initiated-sso-and-idp-initiated-sso) they discuss the differences but they don't talk about the XML level itself...

The SAML response looks like this:

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp ="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2 .0 :protocol" Destination ="http: //my - sp . com /sso /saml" ID ="_45307c23795120" IssueInstant ="2014 -03 -07 T08:30:00Z" Version ="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml ="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2 .0 :assertion">http: //my - idp . com </saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value ="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion ID ="ebe015e8be2a" IssueInstant="2014-03-07T08:30:00Z" Version ="2.0">
        <saml:Issuer> http: //my - idp . com </saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds ="http: //www . w3 . org /2000/09/xmldsig #">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm ="http: //www . w3 . org /2001/10/xml - exc - c14n #"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm ="http: //www . w3 . org /2000/09/ xmldsig # rsa - sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI ="# ebe015e8be2a">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm ="http: //www . w3 . org /2000/09/ xmldsig # enveloped - signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm ="http: //www . w3 . org /2001/10/xml - exc - c14n #"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm ="http: //www . w3 . org /2000/09/ xmldsig # sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue> ... </ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue> ... </ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate> ... </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format ="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2 .0 :nameid - format:persistent" NameQualifier ="http: //my - idp . com" SPNameQualifier ="http: //my - sp . com /sso /saml"> NDSUser </saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method ="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter ="2014 -03 -07 T10:45:00Z" Recipient ="http: //my - sp . com /sso /saml"/>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore ="2014 -03 -07 T08:29:00Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014 -03 -07 T10:46:00Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience> http: //my - sp . com /sso /saml </saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014 -03 -07 T08:25:56Z" SessionIndex="f7810a8c86a6">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2 .0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name ="FEDERATION_ID">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs ="http: //www . w3 . org /2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi ="http: //www . w3 . org /2001/XMLSchema - instance" xsi:type ="xs:string"> NDS </saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML response from SP-initiated SSO flow has 'InResponseTo' attribute.